# MVC 4 Error in Layout / HTML

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have got a HTML template which I have added with a .cshtml extension in the application and have made some changes in the file. I have got a large part of the html commmented out and whenever I call this layout on a view. It comes up with an error which is as follows :

"<" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Here is the Code:

```
<li><strong>@<a href="#">name</a></strong> <span class="tweet_text">RT <span class="at">@</span><a href="#">name</a>
```

It shows that the error has occurred in line 240 and line 240 is something like this:
Can anyone help me out with this with? Why is the error showing? Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the code too?

Comment: You need the HTML part I guess..it is something like this..  Line 240:          <li><strong>@<a href="#">name</a></strong> <span class="tweet_text">RT <span class="at">@</span><a href="#">name</a> Donec suscipit vehicula turpis sed

Comment: <span class="tweet_text"> doesn't have a closing? or is it closing somewhere after "<a href="#">name</a>"??

Comment: Alos with the help of "@" are you trying to comment the code? It's causeing due to single "@" symbol only

Comment: @user2719346..thanks! resolved the issue..there were some '@' marks in  between certain lines of code(which were commented out) produced the error.

Comment: I deleted my answer, felt like I added more confusion than clarity. I'd say, update your post with your expected result.. I still think you might want to escape your @ sign with a @@ though.

Comment: @Anton No worries! Yes the problem is that I have this  HTML template which has been designed by someone else in which the Footer part is commented out with some "@" in between the "li" tags..which was the source of error.@user2719346 One more thing that I would like to know is..if the code which consisted of the erroneous part has been commented out then why has the error come up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because @ is like a reserve word in cshtml, it is likely followed by { and enclosed in }, example:`@{var message = "Hello World!";}`, I think if you want to use that character you must enclose it in `<pre>@</pre>` tag.`

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply use another `@` to escape it: `@@` will render as `@` in the generated markup.